# Why isn't the value going to the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a stupid question but I am getting frustrated and hoping for some help.  Why won't my values output to the console after submitting?  Anyone notice issues?

```
var todos = "";

// user clicked on the add button in the to-do field add that text into the to-do text

$('#add-todo').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //values per text box
  todos = $("#todo-input").val().trim();

  //test values from textbox
  console.log(todos);
```

HTML

```
<div class ="col-4">
    <form role = "form">
        <div class = "form-group row">
            <div class = "To-Do-List">
                <label for="todo-input">Add Your To Do List Here:</label>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="todo-input" type = "text">
            <tbody id = "table_body">
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button class ="btn btn-danger" id="add-todo" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when is your script running? Are you wrapping it all in a document.ready?

Comment: when i hit the button i want to be able to take the value from the textbox and have it show in the console.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of the input from within your anonymous click handler...without the trim?

Comment: I've formatted your code. In addition to possibly missing some JavaScript, you have invalid HTML. For example, you open an `input` tag but close it with a `/div`. Please correct these so we can see everything you are doing.

Comment: No he's not, he's got a nested div in there but it's not indented, throwing you off, the input tag is a singleton. That closing div tag isn't an issue...

Comment: Where is your script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need close whit "})"

```js
var todos = "";

// user clicked on the add button in the to-do field add that text into the to-do text

$('#add-todo').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //values per text box
  todos = $("#todo-input").val().trim();

  //test values from textbox
  console.log(todos);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="col-4">
    <form role = "form">
        <div class = "form-group row">
        <div class = "To-Do-List">
            <label for="todo-input">Add Your To Do List Here:</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="todo-input" type = "text">
            <tbody id = "table_body">
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="button">
<button class ="btn btn-danger" id="add-todo" type="submit">Add</button></div>
```

Comment: this works on the code snippit but for some reason is still not working in my system.

Comment: You need execute this when the document is load

Comment: I'm pretty new to this not sure what that means

Comment: great thank you. Sorry for the newbie question but why do i need to do that? if you aren't interested in answering I'll just research it myself just thought i'd ask

Comment: If you want to get resources from your html, you need this loaded.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and thanks again for the help

Comment: add this character ";" at the end of "})"